# Python large list manipulation

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have python list like below:

```
DEMO_LIST = [
    [{'unweighted_criket_data': [-46.14554728131345, 2.997789122813151, -23.66171024766996]},
     {'weighted_criket_index_input': [-6.275794430258629, 0.4076993207025885, -3.2179925936831144]},
     {'manual_weighted_cricket_data': [-11.536386820328362, 0.7494472807032877, -5.91542756191749]},
     {'average_weighted_cricket_data': [-8.906090625293496, 0.5785733007029381, -4.566710077800302]}],

    [{'unweighted_football_data': [-7.586729834820534, 3.9521665714843675, 5.702038461085529]},
     {'weighted_football_data': [-3.512655913521907, 1.8298531225972623, 2.6400438074826]},
     {'manual_weighted_football_data': [-1.8966824587051334, 0.9880416428710919, 1.4255096152713822]},
     {'average_weighted_football_data': [-2.70466918611352, 1.4089473827341772, 2.0327767113769912]}],

    [{'unweighted_rugby_data': [199.99999999999915, 53.91020408163265, -199.9999999999995]},
     {'weighted_rugby_data': [3.3999999999999857, 0.9164734693877551, -3.3999999999999915]},
     {'manual_rugby_data': [49.99999999999979, 13.477551020408162, -49.99999999999987]},
     {'average_weighted_rugby_data': [26.699999999999886, 7.197012244897959, -26.699999999999932]}],

    [{'unweighted_swimming_data': [2.1979283454982053, 14.079951031527246, -2.7585499298828777]},
     {'weighted_swimming_data': [0.8462024130168091, 5.42078114713799, -1.062041723004908]},
     {'manual_weighted_swimming_data': [0.5494820863745513, 3.5199877578818115, -0.6896374824707194]},
     {'average_weighted_swimming_data': [0.6978422496956802, 4.470384452509901, -0.8758396027378137]}]]
```

I want to manipulate list items and do some basic math operation,like getting each data type list (example taking all first element of unweighted data and do sum etc)

Currently I am doing it like [this](http://pastebin.com/QqBA7QXH).

The current solution is a very basic one, I want to do it in such way that if the list length is grown, it can automatically calculate the results. Right now there are four list, it can be 5 or 8,the final result should be the summation of all the first element of unweighted values,example:

```
now I am doing result_u1/4,result_u2/4,result_u3/4
I want it like result_u0/4,result_u1/4.......result_n4/4 # n is the number of list inside demo list
```

Any idea how I can do that?

(sorry for the beginner question)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a specific list class for yourself, that adds your summary with new item's values in append function, or decrease them on remove:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.summary = 0
        list.__init__(self)

    def append(self, item):
        self.summary += item.sample_value
        list.append(self, item)

    def remove(self, item):
        self.summary -= item.sample_value
        list.remove(self, item)
```

And a simple usage:

```
my_list = MyList()
print my_list.summary  # Outputs 0
my_list.append({'sample_value': 10})
print my_list.summary # Outputs 10
```

Comment: can you elaborate it,with some more details?

Comment: Are you changing data in your code after appending that? If It's true then every thing will be harder. But in append and Remove it's as simple as I coded (I had fixed my code, recheck please).

Answer (score 0):

Start by replacing this:

```
for i in range(0,len(data_list)-1):
    result_u1+=data_list[i][0].values()[0][0]
    result_u2+=data_list[i][0].values()[0][1]
    result_u3+=data_list[i][0].values()[0][2]
print "UNWEIGHTED",result_u1/4,result_u2/4,result_u3/4
```

With this:

```
sz = len(data_list[i][0].values()[0])
result_u = [0] * sz
for i in range(0,len(data_list)-1):
    for j in range(0,sz):
        result_u[j] += data_list[i][0].values()[0][j]
print "UNWEIGHTED", [x/len(data_list) for x in result_u]
```

Apply similar changes elsewhere. This assumes that your data really is "rectangular", that is to say every corresponding inner list has the same number of values.

A slightly more "Pythonic"[*] version of:

```
for j in range(0,sz):
    result_u[j] += data_list[i][0].values()[0][j]
```

is:

```
for j, dataval in enumerate(data_list[i][0].values()[0]):
    result_u[j] += dataval
```

There are some problems with your code, though:

- `values()[0]` might give you *any* of the values in the dictionary, since dictionaries are unordered. Maybe it happens to give you the unweighted data, maybe not.
- I'm confused why you're looping on the range 0 to `len(data_list)-1`: if you want to include all the sports you need `0` to `len(data_list)`, because the second parameter to `range`, the upper limit, is *excluded*.

You could perhaps consider reformatting your data more like this:

```
DEMO_LIST = {
    'cricket' : {
        'unweighted' : [1,2,3],
        'weighted' : [4,5,6],
        'manual' : [7,8,9],
        'average' : [10,11,12],
    },
    'rugby' : ...
}
```

Once you have the same keys in each sport's dictionary, you can replace `values()[0]` with `['unweighted']`, so you'll always get the right dictionary entry. And once you have a whole lot of dictionaries all with the same keys, you can replace them with a class or a named tuple, to define/enforce that those are the values that must always be present:

```
import collections
Sport = collections.namedtuple('Sport', 'unweighted weighted manual average')
DEMO_LIST = {
    'cricket' : Sport(
        unweighted = [1,2,3],
        weighted = [4,5,6],
        manual = [7,8,9],
        average = [10,11,12],
    ),
    'rugby' : ...
}
```

Now you can replace `['unweighted']` with `.unweighted`.

[*] The word "Pythonic" officially means something like, "done in the style of a Python programmer, taking advantage of any useful Python features to produce the best idiomatic Python code". In practice it usually means "I prefer this, and I'm a Python programmer, therefore this is the correct way to write Python". It's an argument by authority if you're Guido van Rossum, or by appeal to nebulous authority if you're not. In almost all circumstances it can be replaced with "good IMO" without changing the sense of the sentence ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, whenever you start counting how many there are of something inside an iterable (a string, a list, a set, a collection of any of these) in order to loop over it - its a sign that your code can be revised.

Things can can work for 3 of something, can work for 300, 3000 and 3 million of the same thing without changing your code.

In your case, your logic is - *"For every `X` inside `DEMO_LIST`, do something"*

This translated into Python is:

```
for i in DEMO_LIST:
   # do something with i
```

This snippet will run through any size of `DEMO_LIST` and each time `i` is each of whatever is in side `DEMO_LIST`. In your case it is the list that contains your dictionaries.

Further expanding on that, you can say:

```
   for i in DEMO_LIST:
      for k in i:
         # now you are in each list that is inside the outer DEMO_LIST
```

Expanding this to do a practical example; a sum of all `unweighted_criket_data`:

```
   all_unweighted_cricket_data = []
   for i in DEMO_LIST:
       for k in i:
         if 'unweighted_criket_data' in k:
             for data in k['unweighted_cricket_data']:
                  all_unweighted_cricked_data.append(data)

   sum_of_data = sum(all_unweighted_cricket_data)
```

There are various "shortcuts" to do the same, but you can appreciate those once you understand the "expanded" version of what the shortcut is trying to do.

Remember there is nothing wrong with writing it out the 'long way' especially when you are not sure of the best way to do something. Once you are comfortable with the logic, then you can use shortcuts like list comprehensions.